# Push Docker image to ECR using CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, gitlab-ci, docker-registry

I am new to Devops.

As part of gitci, I have a Docker file in GitLab. I am planning to create a Docker image and push it to ECR and then use that image for batch processing.

I have already completed batch processing part using existing image in ECR. But not able to create Docker image and push using CloudFormation.

Should I use command in init?

Thanks in advance gurus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem at work and sumbled across this already asked question that does not have a proper answer, so I'll give instructions of how I did.

Baseline: you cannot do this with cloudformation, cloudformation is used to create infrastructure and automations. Although, you can accomplish this with codebuild and you can use cloudformation to create a codebuild project. This [repository](https://github.com/caiocsgomes/flask-ecs) does that for a practical example.

What you would do is: create a cloudformation template that creates a codebuild project and in your codebuild create a buildspec.yml (file that specifies the build) that will push your image to ECR.

The codebuild project would look like this:

```
CodeBuildProject:
Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
Properties:
  Artifacts:
    Type: CODEPIPELINE
  Description: "Codebuild project to push flask api image to ecr"
  Environment:
    ComputeType:
      !FindInMap [CodeBuildComputeTypeMap, !Ref GithubBranch, type]
    EnvironmentVariables:
      - Name: AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
        Value: !Ref AWS::Region
      - Name: AWS_ACCOUNT_ID
        Value: !Ref "AWS::AccountId"
      - Name: AWS_ECR_REPOSITORY_URI
        Value: !Sub ${AWS::AccountId}.dkr.ecr.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${EcrRepository}
      - Name: IMAGE_REPO_NAME
        Value: !Ref GithubRepository
      - Name: IMAGE_TAG
        Value: "latest"
    Image: "aws/codebuild/standard:5.0"
    PrivilegedMode: true
    Type: "LINUX_CONTAINER"
  ServiceRole: !GetAtt CodeBuildRole.Arn
  Source:
    Type: "CODEPIPELINE"
    BuildSpec: buildspec.yml

EcrRepository:
     Type: AWS::ECR::Repository
     Properties:
       RepositoryName: !Ref GithubRepository

CodeBuildRole:
Type: AWS::IAM::Role
Properties:
  AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
    Version: "2012-10-17"
    Statement:
      - Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          Service:
            - codebuild.amazonaws.com
        Action:
          - "sts:AssumeRole"
  Policies:
    - PolicyName: "PushImageToEcr"
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - ecr:BatchGetImage
              - ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability
              - ecr:CompleteLayerUpload
              - ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer
              - ecr:InitiateLayerUpload
              - ecr:PutImage
              - ecr:UploadLayerPart
              - ecr:GetAuthorizationToken
            Resource: "*"
    - PolicyName: "CodeBuildLogsRole"
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - logs:CreateLogGroup
              - logs:CreateLogStream
              - logs:PutLogEvents
            Resource:
              - !Sub "arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:/aws/codebuild/*"
    - PolicyName: "GetAndPutArtifacts"
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Action:
              - s3:GetObject
              - s3:PutObject
              - s3:ListBucket
            Resource:
              - !GetAtt ArtifactBucket.Arn
              - !Sub ${ArtifactBucket.Arn}/*

ArtifactBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
```

This should go in the **Resources** section of the cloudformation and will create the codebuild project, the ecr repository, the codebuild service role and the s3 bucket for the artifacts.

Then you need a **buildspec.yml** template to push your image, this would look like this:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image...
      - cd app/
      - docker build -t $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG .
      - docker tag $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker image...
      - docker push $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do it using CloudFormation as it's not intended to do this style of operation.

However, you mentioned that you're using gitlab-ci. This means you could easily create a job that build your docker image and uploads it to ECR.

In my opinion, it's even easier to create a CodeBuild project (using CloudFormation, IaC FTW!) that handle the building and uploading of your Docker image. The advantage of CodeBuild over GitLab-ci is that you'll be able to give the proper ECR access to the CodeBuild worker for it to upload the image to the repository.

Comment: Do you think it's better to put your buildspec.yml directly into your cloudformation template or to keep a buildspec file in the repository for this use case?

Comment: That's a good question JIMPRO, I think having it the repository gives you more flexibility you can have different buildspecs for different branches. However, if maintainer of the repo is not a direct stakeholder of the automation (maybe for security concerns) you can "hide" the buildspec inside the CodeBuild project definition.